# Solidity: Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number "8e+22" to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to connect a website to mint a nft on the chain but when the button ask to metamask to make the mint transaction it appears this error with problem WEI cost. It gets the value on a JSON file.
On config it is WEI_COST: 80000000000000000000000.
I'm using the HashLips Minting Dapp.
From what I understand, the number is too long for the code to accept it, what should I modify so that it takes it without problems?

```
Uncaught Error: Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number "8e+22" to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "1.6e+23"
    at c (utils.js:59:15)
    at Object.m (utils.js:238:18)
    at formatters.js:145:30
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at u (formatters.js:144:8)
    at d.inputTransactionFormatter (formatters.js:172:15)
    at index.js:128:38
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at d.formatInput (index.js:126:32)
    at d.toPayload (index.js:159:23)
```

c (utils.js:59:15)

```
var toBN = function (number) {
    try {
        return numberToBN.apply(null, arguments);
    }
    catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e + ' Given value: "' + number + '"');
    }
};
```

Object.m (utils.js:238:18)

```
var numberToHex = function (value) {
    if ((value === null || value === undefined)) {
        return value;
    }
    if (!isFinite(value) && !isHexStrict(value)) {
        throw new Error('Given input "' + value + '" is not a number.');
    }
    var number = toBN(value);
    var result = number.toString(16);
    return number.lt(new BN(0)) ? '-0x' + result.substr(1) : '0x' + result;
};
```

formatters.js:145:30

```
}).forEach(function (key) {
        options[key] = utils.numberToHex(options[key]);
    });
```

u (formatters.js:144:8)

```
}
    ['gasPrice', 'gas', 'value', 'maxPriorityFeePerGas', 'maxFeePerGas', 'nonce'].filter(function (key) {
        return options[key] !== undefined;
    }).forEach(function (key) {
        options[key] = utils.numberToHex(options[key]);
    });
    return options;
```

Code invoking the transaction

```
const claimNFTs = () => {
    let cost = 80000000000000000000000;
    let gasLimit = CONFIG.GAS_LIMIT;
    let totalCostWei = String(cost * mintAmount);
    let totalGasLimit = String(gasLimit * mintAmount);
    console.log("Cost: ", totalCostWei);
    console.log("Gas limit: ", totalGasLimit);
    setFeedback(`Minting your ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME}...`);
    setClaimingNft(true);
    blockchain.smartContract.methods
      .mint(mintAmount)
      .send({
        gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit),
        to: CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        from: blockchain.account,
        value: totalCostWei,
      })
      .once("error", (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setFeedback("Sorry, something went wrong please try again later.");
        setClaimingNft(false);
      })
      .then((receipt) => {
        console.log(receipt);
        setFeedback(
          `Congratulations, you minted ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME}.`
        );
        setClaimingNft(false);
        dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
      });
  };
```

I tried to make the mint function works but i doesn't work because the number to use a gwei is large

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your writing the wei cost as a number instead of a string:

```
let cost = '80000000000000000000000';
```

the other form will cause javascript to convert it to e notation